# FFmpeg lenscorrection filter creates bad moire patterns

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing, distortion

I'm trying to create a barrel distortion effect using FFmpeg.  The `lenscorrection` filter can do this, but depending on the source material the results can be pretty bad, with moire patterns / bad interpolation.

Source image

[image]

Result with FFmpeg

[image]
(using: `-vf lenscorrection=k1=0.1:k2=0.1`): terrible moire interference here. My guess is that the lenscorrection filter uses nearest-neighbor interpolation, and this doesn't seem to be configurable.

I get better results from both ImageMagick and Photoshop here's a Photoshop example for comparison.

[image]

For single images that works fine, but I need a way to do this with FFmpeg for video.

Is there a better way? Any tips?

---

**Edit**, following the comments: there are at least two ways to improve the FFmpeg results, but they don't really work for real-world usage since they have roughly the same (big) drawback:

1. **Upscale the image** by a large factor before feeding it to lenscorrection, and downscale it afterwards.  This effectively eliminates moire, and looks even better if I add a little gaussian blur as a lowpass filter. For example:
   `ffmpeg -i in.png -vf "scale=iw*8:ih*8:flags=neighbor, lenscorrection=k1=.1:k2=.1, gblur=9:1:15:2, scale=iw/8:ih/8:flags=lanczos" out.png`

   [image]

   Drawback: the larger the scaling factor, the better the result; it starts looking acceptable at 8x, but for large videos these scale factors are hardly practical, due to extreme CPU/memory overhead.
2. Use the **v360** filter, which does support better interpolation methods (default is bilinear).  For instance: `ffmpeg -i 1s.png -vf v360=flat:fisheye:ih_fov=60:v_fov=45:h_fov=60:v_fov=45:w=360:h=240 out.png` -

   [image]

   Drawback: I can't find an intuitive way to control the *amount* of distortion.  It can be reduced by padding the frame, so that the image occupies a smaller proportion of its area (=equivalent to moving the 'lens' further away). But then, for smaller distortions, the frame sizes quickly become unmanageable - same problem as method #1.

So I'm still looking for a better solution if it exists.

Comment: Try v360 filter instead, with all correct parameters it is doable.

Comment: @PaulB.Mahol: thanks, I was actually just playing with v360's options to convert from 'flat' to 'fisheye' formats.  This works but I cannot find an adequate way to control the amount of distortion beyond a narrow range... if I cannot figure it out I'll update the question.

Comment: You can use hacky workaround like oversampling, upsample input to 2x/4x/8x width/height, filter with lenscorrection and then downsample to 0.5x/0.25x/0x125 width/height, Use scale filter for this.

Comment: Added bilinear interpolation to lenscorrection filter.

Comment: @PaulB.Mahol: thanks! Tested and answered.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by Paul B. Mahol's Jan 25 addition.  It's now possible to specify bilinear interpolation for lenscorrection, which nicely solves the moire issue. For instance: `lenscorrection=k1=.1:k2=.1:i=bilinear`